# Does fast exponentiation algorithm work with matrices?

Tags: matrices, fibonacci-numbers

I am trying to create a function which retrieves the $n^{th}$ position of the Fibonnaci sequence, defined by:

$F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$

I have found the following relation, which is true,

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}^n
=
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{n+1} & F_n\\
F_n & F_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$

My question is whether using the fast exponentiation algorithm that works. I have made this approach in python but it does not work,

```
def fastExponentiationAlgo(a, b):
    y = [[1,0], [0,1]] # identity matrix
    while b > 1:
        if b % 2 != 0:
            y = product(y, a)
        a = product(a, a)
        b = b / 2
    return product(y, a)
```

where $product$, it is a function which retrieves the product of two matrices.

```
print(fastExponentiationAlgo([[1,1], [1,0]], 20))
```

Where $[[1,1], [1,0]]$ it's the base and 20 the exponent. $F_{20}$ is $6765$ but this piece of code retrieves $1548008755920$ instead which make me think that fast exponentiation algorithm does not apply to matrices.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: For sure, the fast exp algorithm should work for matrices. It looks like you are trying to write the iterative version which is at the bottom of this wiki page section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Basic_method 

However, it looks like your version of the algorithm might be flawed, even for numbers.

Comment: Just tried and it works, provided `b=b/2` is meant as an INTEGER division (don't know how it is coded in Python).

Comment: AnonymousCoward , Yes you are right, the code is flawed. Fixed and everythin is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the fast exponentiation algorithm works with matrices; in fact, it works with *any* associative operation with an identity element. (and with care, you can even eliminate the need for the identity element)

It turns out your problem is a programming one, not a math one: you've misimplemented the fast exponentiation algorithm.

The error I spotted is that `b = b / 2` is computing the wrong thing: the thing you're supposed to compute here is `b = b // 2`.  I haven't checked if your implementation is otherwise correct.

Comment: The problem was the code. Already fixed and working. God bless Fast Exponentiation Algorithm. Thank you for your contribution.